# DCount function of MSAccess in Visual Studio project not declared

Tags: dcount

I want to use the DCount function in my Visual Studio Project but DCount gets underlined with a squiggly line and the tooltip says "Not declared" What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using in Visual Studio (I suspect VB.NET), but DCount is not available neither VB.NET nor C#, it is an Access VBA function. It can't be used in SQL queries either, when you want to retrieve data from Access.

You can count the number of records however by using a SQL expression like 
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExampleTable WHERE FieldToCount = 'SpecificSelection'` 

or using LINQ.

Comment: Thank you very much